# Installing database when create a clone of website in local server

Tags: database, wordpress

G'day, I am trying to make a clone of the WordPress website into my local server. I installed the Duplicator plugin and generated a archive file of the website and the installer.php. Then after ran the installer.php from http://localhost:8888/untitledfolder/installer.php.

In the step 2 (Install Database) there is an error which is a connection failure. I already created a database named 'livewebsite' beforehand. It's likewise the below image.

[image: Error screenshot]

Any help would be really appreciated though I am new to WordPress trying to learn from the scratch. No down votes for the question please. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. That was my username and password. Username & password should be default data which is root and 123 for my settings. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should change MySQL port (the right input with localhost) from 8888 to 3306. That's the real port of MySQL server.

After change and retry, you can see the Host: Fail will become Host: Success with green flag I think. If Database still have a red fail flag, please edit your database username and password. **It's not** your WordPress account.